# Json decode store in single var

Tags: php

Hie all,
I have `$ID="1,2,3,";//like this`
I wanted to pass it within function somewhat like..

```
<input type="submit"  onclick="<?php echo 'edit($ID)';?>">
```

I have $ID in json_encoded format. I want to decode it. and store each in single var.

```
foreach()
{
// single var store each decoded ..
}
```

Comment: foreach(), input are in same php file? please add some more code

Comment: nope i dont want hidden and all.. I just want encoded json to decode and store in single var..thats it.

Comment: can you explain a little more waht are you trying to do?

Comment: use, json_decode($str, true);

Comment: and what is edit($ID) ?

Answer (score 0):

In file1 save id in hidden field,

```
<form method="get" action="file2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="<?php echo $ID;?>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In file2 get like this,

```
$id = $_GET['ids'];
$id_arr = explode(',',$id);  // gives array
```